# ajax form input to database post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database, forms

i am trying for hours now, cant get it to work

my ajax call

```
 $('.button').click( function() {
         var mail = $("#mail_content").val();

         alert(mail);

        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "process.php",  
            data: "mail="+ mail,  
            success: function(){  
                alert("success");  
            }  
        });
    });
```

my process.php

```
<?php
//  echo "<pre>";
//  print_r($_POST);
//  echo "</pre>";

include 'config.php';
include 'lib.php';

$db = dbConnect();


$mail = quote_smart($_POST['mail']);

//insert, update, select, delete
$query = "INSERT INTO mail VALUES ('', '$mail')";
$result = insertQuery($query);


 dbClose($db);

echo "entry saved";

?>
```

my form

```
<div class="email">
            <div class="email_title">GET NOTIFIED FOR THE GRAND OPENING<br /> </div>
            <div id="contact_form">
              <form id="mail" name="mail" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <fieldset>
                  <label for="mail" id="email_label">YOUR EMAIL</label>
                  <input type="text" name="mail_content" id="mail_content" size="30" value="" class="text-input" />
                  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="SAVE" />
                </fieldset>
              </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

am i overlooking something?
it works when i put the process.php code in the action in the form

Comment: form:<div class="email">
    <div class="email_title">GET NOTIFIED FOR THE GRAND OPENING<br /> </div>
    <div id="contact_form">
      <form id="mail" name="mail" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <fieldset>
          <label for="mail" id="email_label">YOUR EMAIL</label>
          <input type="text" name="mail_content" id="mail_content" size="30" value="" class="text-input" />
          <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="SAVE" />
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
   </div>

Comment: Did you know that you can edit your own post to add more information to the thread? Please have a look to the FAQ : http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: change it to $("#mail").submit(function(){}); instead of button click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your ajax call as below ... This also solves submitting with enter issue.

```
 $('#mail').submit( function() {
        var mail = $("#mail_content").val();
        alert(mail);
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "process.php",  
            data: "mail="+ mail,  
            success: function(){  
                alert("success");  
            }  
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: when i use that it does not submit and does not give me any alerts either, i also tried to bind another action to pressing the enter key but does not work

Comment: in order to make this work you have to use <input type="submit"....  if you have converted that button in sample to <input type="button" please revert it back

Answer (score 1):

first thing I see is, your `.button` is a submit input, so when you click it, the form will be submitted, instead of the ajax call.

Make it a button

```
<input type="button" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="SAVE" />
```

Comment: one more problem, when i hit enter, it behaves like a submit.

Comment: Sorry but using a "button" as a ajax submit button is usually not a good idea.